# What is the meaning of a>>>0 in javascript? where a is an integer variable holding a value in js

Tags: javascript, javascript-debugging

I tried to do a small poc to understand this in detail like .

var a = -1;

a>>>0;

var a = 0;
a>>>0.

I know this is right shift zero fill binary operator but what does >>>0 this do. Can anyone explain in detail please

Comment: May be you will get a better answer on stackoverflow here https://stackoverflow.com/q/10382122/7664109 , as this is purely javascript

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't shift the number, it just sets the sign bit to 0. It also convert the original value to number.
Keep in mind that output of the bitwise shift operators is a **32-bit** number.
It means that if the original value is greater than 4294967295 (`(2^32)-1`), the output will be 4294967295.
If the left operand is Infinity, NaN, null, Array or an Object, the output will be 0.

```js
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER); // A number greater than 4294967295 
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER >>> 0); // 4294967295 
// -1 = 0xFFFFFFFF = every bit is 1
// setting just the sign bit to 0 you get the max 32 bit int
console.log(-1 >>> 0); // 4294967295
console.log('-1' >>> 0); // 4294967295
console.log(Infinity >>> 0); // 0
console.log(NaN >>> 0); // 0
console.log(null >>> 0); // 0
console.log([] >>> 0); // 0
console.log({} >>> 0); // 0
console.log(Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER >> 0); // -1 (because the output is a 32 bit number)
```